# Enabling pcntl_fork on beanstalk aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, pcntl

I Am using Elastic Beanstalk Linux AMI with PHP. When I run this on the terminal:

```
php -m | grep pcntl
```

I see `pcntl` but when I try using `pcntl_fork()` function it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work does not necessarily mean it doesn't exist. What's wrong exactly?